# Get JPanel in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jviewport

I have a JScrollPane and I put a JPanel in the JScrollPane. The JPanel holds a variable amount of JLabels.

Here is how I "new" it:

```
JPanel dataPanel  = new JPanel();
//then do a for loop to put a few JLabels in dataPanel
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dataPanel);
```

I was wondering how I can get those JLabel in another class? I tried the following code but doesn't work coming with a ClassCastException. In that class, I succeed to get the JScrollPane and I will use scrollPane to represent it.

```
//I only put a panel in the JScrollPane, so I used 0 in the getComponent() method
JPanel panel = scrollPane.getComponent(0);
for(int i = 0; i < panel.getComponentCount(); i++){
    JLabel label = (JLabel)panel.getComponent(i);
}
```

In fact, at the statement:

```
JPanel panel = scrollPane.getComponent(0);
```

The ClassCastException is thrown.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JViewport cannot be cast to javax.swing.JPanel
```

Appreciated for help :)

Answer (score 5):

[JScrollPane#getViewport#getView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#getView())

You'll have to cast out back to your component type

The better solution would be to maintain a list of the `JLabel`s in an array or `List`